# How do I solve PHP Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() when install a new laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

PHP Deprecated:

> Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should
> either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator():
> Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used
> to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/danielikokoh/.composer/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php
> on line 104

Crafting application...

In RequestException.php line 113:

Server error: `GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip` resulted in a `52 0`  response

Comment: What do you get if you do `php -v`?